# Export Excel using Displaytag

Tags: java, decorator, displaytag

I am using Display tag for displaying the results in table.
I am using Decorator class to customize the look on some columns

I have a column where I am displaying the result which is customized by decorator

```
public String getMyLink(){
    return "<a href='"+getCurrentRowObject().getLink()+"'>Details</a>";
}
```

This is getting displayed as I am expecting.

But when I export the results as Xml/Excel or any other format, I am getting the column detail as "http://myLink'>Details"

But I want it to be imported as http ://myLink (no extra decorator data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Thanks :)

http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/tut_decorators.html#Table_decorators_and_exports